# 3060102 reversible_guard_exception

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosio-code

I am facing this issue after 3 month when i ran the node,

3060102 reversible_guard_exception: Reversible block log usage is at unsafe levels
reversible free: 2096992, guard size: 2097152
{"f":2096992,"g":2097152}

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by too small of a setting for reversible-blocks-db-size-mb. Increase this value. You likely will also want to increase chain-state-db-size-mb as well.